# Surface Objects wrongly obscure each other in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a sphere on a plane using matplotlib and encounter this problem: [image: https://imgur.com/a/7b4lgf0]

The plane is normal to z-axis with the sphere tangent to it from above. Both are plotted using `Axes3D.plot_surface`.

When I rotate the axes towards a top view, the sphere suddenly appears. Otherwise, the sphere is obscured behind the plane.
I tried using zorder property in plot_surface for both objects but that didn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Classic case of [My 3D plot doesn't look right at certain viewing angles](https://matplotlib.org/api/toolkits/mplot3d/faq.html#my-3d-plot-doesn-t-look-right-at-certain-viewing-angles).